# Java base64 encode and decode

Tags: java, base64

I am trying to encode `byte[]` to `String`, then decode this `String` to `byte[]`, my code is:

```
byte[] aaa = new byte[1];
aaa[0] = (byte) 153;

String encoder = Base64.encodeBase64String(aaa);
System.out.println("encoder <<>> " + encoder);

// Decode the Base64 String.        
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encoder);
String decoder = new String(bytes, "UTF08");
System.out.println("decoder <<>> " + decoder );
```

Result is:

```
encoder <<>> mQ==
decoder <<>> ?
```

The result are not the same one. Why does this happen?

Comment: Of course it is not the same. You are interpreting the byte as UTF-8, while what you want to do is to print out the value of the byte instead.

Comment: Like nhatdh said, just do: 
System.out.println("decoder <<>> " + bytes[0]);

Comment: I have tried, and i print the value of bytes, result is -103, code is:

Comment: -103 is what you would expect. Java's `byte` type is signed, so the maximum value it can hold is 127. When you cast 153 (an int) to a byte you get the bit pattern 10011001. When interpreted as a twos-complement number this is -103.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
byte[] aaa = new byte[1];
aaa[0] = (byte) 153;
System.out.println("original bytes <<>> " + Arrays.toString(aaa));

// Encode the bytes to Base64
String encoder = Base64.encodeBase64String(aaa);
System.out.println("encoder <<>> " + encoder);

// Decode the Base64 String to bytes
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encoder);
System.out.println("decoded bytes <<>> " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response, i try it, the print result is: original bytes <<>> [-103]
encoder <<>> mQ==
decoded bytes <<>> [-103]    i don't know why? what can i do for this problem?

Comment: @TonyChou - That's actually correct. Java bytes are always signed quantities. The maximum byte value is +127. When you cast 153 to a byte, it comes out to 0x99. (When values overflow in Java, they just silently wrap around within the allowed range.) Finally, 0x99 is -103 in two's complement. If you need to see a positive value, you need to do something like `byteValue & 0xff`. That promotes `byteValue` to an `int` and then masks off any sign extension that might have taken place.

Answer (score 0):

simple static utility methods to encode and decode the given string.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
...

private static byte[] key = {
        0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x49, 0x73, 0x41, 0x53, 0x65, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x4b, 0x65, 0x79
    };  // "ThisIsASecretKey";

    public static String encrypt(String stringToEncrypt) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        final String encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(stringToEncrypt.getBytes()));
        return encryptedString;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String stringToDecrypt) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        final String decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(stringToDecrypt)));
        return decryptedString;
    }
```